# Module turtle most have atribute shape?

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
import turtle
turtle.shape("turtle")
```

I try to use turtle module but idle throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Ariel/Programacion Web/Python/programas/ejer60.py", line 2, in <module>
    turtle.shape("turtle")
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'shape'
```

and i know shape is an attribute. What is happening? Is this something to do with version 3.8.3 that I have installed?

Comment: From the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.shape, your code looks fine. Please check that you have not named your script filename as `turtle.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some version problem or you are doing something wrong, as for me it is working fine.
output
`'turtle'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved including turtle module at the path browser.